# How can we display a dialog on top of the existing dialogs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider a scenario in which we have an input box where we can type commands and corresponding to each command a dialog opens. So, if we keep typing commands and opening dialogs then how can we display new dialog on top of existing dialogs. Like displaying 2nd dialog on top of first dialog and 3rd on top of 2nd dialog and so on..

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: css z-index!  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
let dialogsEl = document.querySelector('.dialogs-container');

inputEl.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let dialog = document.createElement('div');
    dialog.classList.add('dialog');
    dialog.innerText = inputEl.value;
    dialog.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.remove();
    });
    dialogsEl.appendChild(dialog);
    inputEl.value = '';
  }
});
```

```css
.dialogs-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10%;
}

.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogs-container"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Click a dialog to close">
```